# Problems with parsing HTML data in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

i was trying to migrate a little script in bash to python. But i dont know how to make a Curl request and Grep some information.

I already try to use python3 with sub process but always get error, so i try with BeautifulSoup in python but, since the response is a list in a td i dont know how to get it.

So is there any way to make a curl request in python and pipe with grep and sed?

This is the curl request.

```
locations=$(curl -silent https://example.com/location/$stores | grep -P -o 'Location.*?<div class="row">' | sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' | sed 's/./& - /12')
```

This is my python3 code

```
import requests
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

store = 'Here Store Name'
url = "https://example.com/?store="+store
session = requests.Session()
request = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

for grabtg in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(grabtg.contents[0])
```

And  the response i get is this, but the only this i need is the StoreNames

```
Store Name
ID
Employes
1
StoreName1
4827489
100
2
StoreName2
4827499
150
3
StoreName3
4827480
220
```

But is the response is bigger than 3 Stores i get this error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Ideally would be to post what you have tried so far in Python...

Comment: what's the actual url?

Comment: May I suggest that the _bash_ tag is removed. The question seems to be unrelated to bash.

Comment: If all you need is the store names then don't print _all_ the table cells. Also, don't assume `grabtg.contents` has data (as you currently do) because clearly, it sometimes doesn't. HTML parsing comes with a lot of `if` checks.

Comment: @JanWilamowski The problem is all other info is inside other td tags, is there a way to select the td every x number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the actual URL or HTML but if you wanted to select the first cell in each row, you could try:

```py
for first_cell in soup.find_all("tr td:first-child"):
    if first_cell:
        print(first_cell.contents)
```